# Groovy how to handle failed library import

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile that always gets run by two webhooks, one for env A and one for env B.

It is guaranteed to always fail in env A. There is an `@Library` for a library that does not exist in env A.

The Jenkinsfile runs fine in env B.

Here's what I want:

```
try {
    @Libray('my-library')
}
catch (whatevs) {
    println "whoops, I'm running in the wrong environment! my-library is unavailable."
    System.exit(0)
}
```

But it doesn't work, it looks like the imports are checked at compile time:

`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: Loading libraries failed`

How can I have the script exit with code 0 when the lib isn't available?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a library that is declared in the 'system' level, using what is called 'Dynamic retrieval' (see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ for full description):

> library identifier: 'custom-lib@master', retriever: modernSCM(
>   [$class: 'GitSCMSource',    remote:
>   'git@git.mycorp.com:my-jenkins-utils.git',    credentialsId:
>   'my-private-key'])

wrapped with try-catch.